# How to set the Authenticator for new RestClient using RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, restsharp

Using .net 6.0 and RestSharp 110.0.1 when I follow the example from the RestSharp documentation (linked below) I get an error "RestClient.Authenticator cannot be assigned to -- it is readonly."

[RestSharp Documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#authenticator)
[GitHub Gist for documentation code](https://gist.github.com/alexeyzimarev/62d77bb25d7aa5bb4b9685461f8aabdd)

```
public class WebInteractionsAuthenticator : AuthenticatorBase {
    readonly string _baseUrl;
    readonly string _clientId;
    readonly string _clientSecret;

    public WebInteractionsAuthenticator(string baseUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret) : base("") {
        _baseUrl      = baseUrl;
        _clientId     = clientId;
        _clientSecret = clientSecret;
    }

    protected override async ValueTask<Parameter> GetAuthenticationParameter(string accessToken) {
        Token = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token) ? await GetToken() : Token;
        return new HeaderParameter(KnownHeaders.Authorization, Token);
    }

    async Task<string> GetToken() {
        var options = new RestClientOptions(_baseUrl);
        using var client = new RestClient(options) {

[tag:// ERROR IS AT FOLLOWING LINE]

            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_clientId, _clientSecret),
        };

        var request = new RestRequest("oauth2/token")
            .AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        var response = await client.PostAsync<TokenResponse>(request);
        return $"{response!.TokenType} {response!.AccessToken}";
    }
}
```

[image: Image of error in Visual Studio]

I've tried looking for alternatives and can't find anything to resolve this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the Obsolete said, we should use  RestClientOptions.Authenticator instead, so I suggest you could try below codes:

```cs
var options = new RestClientOptions();

options.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("","");

using var client = new RestClient(options)
{
     
};
```